# Perl printing precise location

Tags: perl, alignment, printf

I have two print statements, one after the other.

```
print("Number of cars");
printf("%10d","$somevariable");

print("Number of blue cars");
printf("%10d","$somevariable");

print("Number of  red cars");
printf("%10d","$somevariable");
```

My problem is that the value for the variables will not be aligned vertically. It will look like something like this

```
Number of Cars       0
Number of blue Cars      0
Number of Red Cars       0
```

Is there any possible way to align them to a certain point across a horizontal line? For example, always print everything at 80 spaces to the right?

Edit: Outputting to terminal.

Cheers

Comment: that all dependson how long your first column gets, you may have to word count it and then decided on longest string to match the length.. why not attempt output in html ? which you can then use tables to easily show content

Comment: @vahid: HTML? to a terminal? or a text document?

Comment: This is clearly not the actual code that's producing this output, since it's loaded with syntax errors.

Comment: @pavel sure you could output html to terminal then use terminal browser to output something like - lynx dump - but agree that gets too over complicated

Comment: This is not my actual code as my actual code is in a foreach reading through some arrays.

Comment: @James Mclaren - I suggest that you produce a small program to illustrate the issue and update your question to show the code.  It should use as much of your actual code as you can, including your attempt to use pavel's answer.

Answer (score 3):

include the label in the printf:

```
printf("%-20s%10d\n","Number of cars", $somevariable)
printf("%-20s%10d\n","Number blue of cars", $someothervariable)
```

Comment: nice - must say have not been practising perl in a while but that worked well

Comment: This had no effect for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex layouts, consider [Text::SimpleTable](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aSimpleTable), [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aTable),  or [similar](https://metacpan.org/search?q=text%20table)